# re-optimizar o volver a optimizar o reoptimizar

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Cual es el mejor uso de "re-optimizar o volver a optimizar o reoptimizar" 
si tengo que poner en un texto cientifico

"Esto evita desarrollar y re-optimizar ..."

¿cual de las 3 opciones queda mejor?

Comment: ¿hace alguna diferencia que sea para un texto científico o de otro tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con temor a la crítica, siempre evitaría dos infinitivos seguidos, terminaciones -ar y -ar. Yo valoraría "evitando una nueva optimización".

Comment: si tengo "para evitar desarrollar y reoptimizar" ,  ¿como sería mejorla redaccion?  "Evitando una nueva optimización e incluso el desarrollo"} ?

Comment: me gusta. Incluso evitas los dos infinitivos.

Comment: @JoulSauron, gracias por la edición, escribí del teléfono y me dio pereza escribirlo correctamente, algo que sin duda, no debí haberlo hecho.